# How to get last records with conditions from SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to get last records from SQLite but with some conditions.. Let's say I have this table

```
id         course
1           math 
2           english      
3           math       
4           english   
5           chemistry
```

and I need to return records of ids 3,4,5 because for `math` the `id`: 3 is the last(newest) record, for `english` the `id`: 4 is the last(newest) record and so on..

I don't know how to group them and then pick the newest record and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite has a [`rowid`](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) that you can query over it like this:

```
select *   
from Table1 t
where exists (
  select 1
  from Table1 ti  
  where t.course = ti.course
  group by ti.course
  having t.rowid = max(ti.rowid);    -- filtering rows that are newest rows in table
  );
```

[**SQLite Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/05d7ef/16)

Sample Data:

```
| id |    course |      ... hidden rowid |
|----+-----------|      ... -------------|
|  1 |      math |      ...            1 |
|  2 |   english |      ...            2 |
|  3 |      math |      ...            3 |
|  4 |   english |      ...            4 |
|  5 | chemistry |      ...            5 |
|  8 |      test |      ...            6 |
|  7 |      test |      ...            7 |
```

Result:

```
| id |    course |      ... hidden rowid |
|----+-----------|      ... -------------|
|  3 |      math |      ...            3 |
|  4 |   english |      ...            4 |
|  5 | chemistry |      ...            5 |
|  7 |      test |      ...            7 |
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want:

```
select max(id) as id, course
from t
group by course;
```